# Read from socket server in C# in socket client in Android

Tags: c#, android, sockets

My server in C# sends message using this code:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World");
current.Send(data);
```

But in Android I dont know how to read it. Im using this code:

```
byte[] b1 = new byte[2048];
int bytesToRead;
while ((bytesToRead = socket.getInputStream().read(b1)) > 0)
{
    Log.d("test", bytesToRead+"");
}
```

but it returns the length of the message from server. How I am supposed to get the message content sent by server.

Comment: How about checking the contents of b1 since that's where you are reading the data?

Comment: But it looks like the 'while' loop isnt stopping, and nothing prints out. I guess its because of b1 size (2048) which client is waiting to get from server but instead is taking 11 bytes.